# i am using rest easy service with tomcat but error Could not find resource for relative.i have created one java file and web.xml and some jars

Tags: resteasy, web.xml

```
@Path("/dateservice")    
public class RestEasyWebapp {
@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)

public Response getDate() {
String date = null;
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
date = currentDate.toString();
return Response.status(200).entity(date).build();
```

Comment: Please correct the formatting, also the code looks like incomplete.

Comment: i am not able to format

Comment: please tell how to create simple web service wit resteasy without maven?